# What other "timer" libs can I use besides ScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: java, timer

What are my choices to do this?

Will creating many scheduled tasks require more than one thread? I would want to only use one thread to handle all these scheduled tasks.

Currently, I am using this:

```
    // send first message, first message is right away
sendMessage();

// prepare the timer to send second message, 2nd message sends 35 seconds after 1st
final ScheduledFuture<?> future2 = ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(
    sendMessage(),
    initDelay,
    EXE_LENGTH * EXE_LENGTH,
    TimeUnit.SECONDS
);

// kill the process for future2 30 seconds after 2nd message is sent
ses.schedule(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        future2.cancel(true);
    }
}, initDelay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// prepare the timer to send the third message, 3rd message sends 35 seconds after task for 2nd message is killed
final ScheduledFuture<?> future3 = ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(
    sendMessage(),
    initDelay + 2L,
    EXE_LENGTH * EXE_LENGTH,
    TimeUnit.SECONDS
);

// kill the process for future3 30 seconds after 3rd message is sent
ses.schedule(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        future3.cancel(true);       
    }
}, initDelay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// shutdown the whole scheduler after the 3rd process is killed
ses.schedule(new Runnable() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        shutdown(challengeId);
    }
}, initDelay+2L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I'm not too knowledgeable about threads, but I believe this create multiple threads to handle a few tasks.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: @assylias that is what i am currently using, just updated with some code.

Comment: You example uses up to 2 threads. (i) is there a reason why having more than one thread is a problem? (ii) if it is, simply change the first line to `... = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);` (the argument is the maximum number of threads).

Comment: If you have many scheduled tasks and want a lot of control use [quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

Comment: @assylias it's not a problem, but I would prefer only one thread doing the tasks. example, one person, sends out message at time 0, then sends out 2nd message at time +30, then sends out 3rd message at time +60. i just don't think it is necessary to use up more than 1 thread. but when i use one thread, somehow the 3rd task is not done, strangely.

Comment: @yaojiang That is most likely because the second task does not complete, so the thread is not released and can't be reused by the third task. You could add some debugging information in your second task to see where it gets stuck.

Comment: @assylias ive added some more code. when i was testing, i used various timers but always seem to lock up on the third message. was hoping for maybe a different way of doing, instead of using the ScheduledExecutorService

Comment: @yaojiang Why do you need to cancel your tasks? Don't they complete by themselves?

Comment: @assylias if i read the docs correctly, the task would repeat itself at X interval until it is canceled, no?

Comment: @yaojiang Yes, but what is the point of cancelling the task and rescheduling it immediately? Also if you only need to run it once, you have the `schedule` method. I've got to run now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26673/discussion-between-yao-jiang-and-assylias)